# How to display only part of string with CSS

Tags: css

This feels like something that everyone would say to use JavaScript for, but I'm asking anyway.

Take this DOM as an example:

```html
<p>Check out these links:</p>
<a href="https://example.com/foo">foo</a>
<a href="https://example.com/bar">bar</a>
<a href="https://example.com/baz">baz</a>
...
<a href="https://example.com/quux">quux</a>
```

I'm looking for a way that I could show the last part of the URL that is being pointed to, without using JavaScript, or putting it in the HTML.

I was thinking that I might be able to shorten it down to something like this:

```html
<base href="https://example.com/" />

<p>Check out these links:</p>
<a href="foo" />
<a href="bar" />
<a href="baz" />
...
<a href="quux" />
```

With the following CSS:

```css
a::after {
    contents: attr("href");
}
```

But, I have other links on the web page that use relative links to link to scripts, styles, other pages on the domain, etc.

I was thinking that I might be able to split the last part of the string after `/` off and display it, but I'm not sure if strings can be manipulated or even read in CSS at all.

It would be nice if we could control the HTML `href` attribute using CSS, but I doubt that's possible either.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: you are asking a lot fot CSS, this is clearly not a CSS job. CSS is for styling not content manipulation

Comment: @TemaniAfif Know of a way that I could apply the `base` element to only certain parts of a document then?